# Sequelize Select models referenced in parent/child tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

If I have the following tables

Post - id, title, content, categoryId

Category - id, name

And some categories don't have posts linked to them, how can I select only the categories that are referenced from the Posts table

I found this in their github issues, but its code from V1, which no longer works, however it demonstrates, I think, what I would like to accomplish

```
ModelA.findAll({
  include: [ModelB],
  having: 'count(ModelB.id) > 0'
});
```

If `ModelB` is referenced one or more times in `ModelA`, include it.

Edit: I don't really want to include it, as I only need the data from the Category table, and not the Posts table.

I'm using postgres, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

required tag helps you in this.

```
ModelA.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: ModelB,
    required: true
    ]  
});
```

This will only return rows in ModelA which have at least one corresponding entry in ModelB